# React - ReactDOM.render to a div which gets loaded later

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, react-dom

I am trying to use React within my angularjs application.

using something like:

```
 ReactDOM.render(
  <Component prop={prop} />,
  document.getElementById("react-root")
);
```

It works fine if the `"react-root"` div is directly added to the DOM in `index.html`,

but if the `div` is loaded in a `ng-include` template, `React` errors saying **"target container is not a valid DOM element"**

I understand this might be due to the `div` not being in the DOM when `ReactDOM.render` runs as the `ng-inlcude` template is loaded later/async.

I also understand that this is not specifically a `React` problem.

I think I just need to find out a way to call `ReactDOM.render` only after the `div` is available in the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
    let reactRoot = document.getElementById("react-root");

    if(reactRoot){
        ReactDOM.render(
            <Component prop={prop}/>,
        );

        observer.disconnect();
    }
});

observer.observe(document.body, {childList: true});
```